# Facebook Android SDK response.getRequestForPagedResults(GraphResponse.PagingDirection.NEXT) returns null

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api, pagination, facebook-sdk-4.0

I'm using Facebook's Android SDK to retrieve information about the user.

My initial request is the following:

```
GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(
                AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(), this);

Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
parameters.putString("fields", "id,name,events");
request.setParameters(parameters);
request.executeAndWait();
```

and this works fine. The callback looks as follows:

```
@Override
public void onCompleted(JSONObject object, GraphResponse response) {
    User user = parseAndValidateFacebookResponse(object);
    if (user.getEvents().getData().size() != 0) {
       // do stuff here
    } 

    GraphRequest nextRequest = response.getRequestForPagedResults(GraphResponse.PagingDirection.NEXT);
    if (nextRequest != null) {
        Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
        parameters.putString("fields", "id,name,events");
        nextRequest.setParameters(parameters);
        nextRequest.setCallback(this);
        nextRequest.executeAsync();
    }
}
```

I'm able to parse the JSONObject, and when I inspect the raw response, it looks the same as what [Facebook's Graph API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/) gives me.

Part of the JSON (in the raw GraphResponse as well as in the Graph Explorer) describes the pagination:

```
"paging": {
  "cursors": {
    "before": "TVRRek1qTTJOREF3TXpZAMU1qQTFNRG94TmprNE5URTJNREF3T2pFNU9UZAzFPREF4TXpNNU9EUXdPQT09",
    "after": "TVRVM05qYzVNVEkxTlRrMU1ERTJNam94TkRjME1EVTVOakF3T2pFNU9UZAzFPREF4TXpNNU9EUXdPQT09"
  },
  "next": "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.8/customerID/events?access_token=accesstoken"
}
```

However, when I try to fetch the next GraphRequest as part of the GraphResponse, I always get back `null`.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is related to the fact that I was using a `newMeRequest` instead of a "regular" GraphRequest, but I got this working after changing my implementation to the following:

```
 Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
        parameters.putString("fields", "id,name,events");
        parameters.putString("limit", "25");

        new GraphRequest(
                AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(),
                "/" + Profile.getCurrentProfile().getId() + "/events",
                parameters,
                HttpMethod.GET,
                this)
        .executeAsync();

@Override
public void onCompleted(JSONObject object, GraphResponse response) {
    User user = parseAndValidateFacebookResponse(object);
    if (user.getEvents().getData().size() != 0) {
       // do stuff here
    } 

    GraphRequest nextRequest = response.getRequestForPagedResults(GraphResponse.PagingDirection.NEXT);
    if (nextRequest != null) {
        Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
        nextRequest.setParameters(parameters);
        nextRequest.setCallback(this);
        nextRequest.executeAsync();
    }
```

}

Right now I'm able to traverse through the next pages, using `getRequestForPagedResults`.